# Odoo - Change color on Forecast Widget

Tags: widget, forecast, odoo-14

I'm trying to change color of Forecasted Widget in Sales Order view. I figured it is defined in this location odoo/addons/sale_stock/static/src/xml/sale_stock.xml this part of code:

```
<div t-name="sale_stock.qtyAtDate">
    <div t-att-class="!widget.data.display_qty_widget ? 'invisible' : ''">
        <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart {{ widget.data.forecasted_issue ? 'text-danger' : 'text-primary' }}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created custom module and tried to replace above code with my version like this (it should be red when Available Qty = 0, Yellow when Available Qty < 5 and green when Available Qty > 5) but with no luck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <xpath expr="//div[@t-name='sale_stock.qtyAtDate']" position="replace">
        <div t-att-class="!widget.data.display_qty_widget ? 'invisible' : ''">
            <div t-elif="widget.data.forecasted_issue == 0">
                <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart text-danger"/>
            </div>
            <div t-if="widget.data.forecasted_issue < 5">
                <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart text-warning"/>
            </div>
            <div t-elif="widget.data.forecasted_issue > 5">
                <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart text-primary"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</templates>
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to change color of this icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For v14 - this is working solution - just put this in your XML file. For v15 use solution @Kenly provided.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-inherit="sale_stock.qtyAtDate" t-operation="replace">
        <xpath expr="//div" position="replace">
            <div t-att-class="!widget.data.display_qty_widget ? 'invisible' : ''">
            <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart {{ widget.data.forecasted_issue ? 'text-danger' : widget.data.qty_available_today &gt; 5 ? 'text-primary' : 'text-warning'}}"/>
            </div>    
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Thank you @Kenly for your help, you made some things clear for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Odoo will raise the following error (terminal):

```
XMLSyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
```

You need to escape `<` and `>`.

If you fix the above error, You will see the following error message in the browser console:

```
Error: QWeb2: Error: t-elif and t-else directives must be preceded by a t-if or t-elif directive
```

You just need to change the div's order (You may need to add `widget.data.product_uom_qty != 0` to the `t-if`).

Check the Odoo documentation on how to [alter qweb templates](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#template-inheritance)

*Extension inheritance (in-place transformation):*

```
<t t-inherit="base.template" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <xpath expr="//tr[1]" position="after">
        <tr><td>new cell</td></tr>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

***Example:***

```
<templates>
    <t t-inherit="sale_stock.qtyAtDate" t-inherit-mode="extension">
        <xpath expr="//div" position="replace">
            <div t-att-class="!widget.data.display_qty_widget ? 'invisible' : ''">
                <div t-if="widget.data.product_uom_qty != 0 and widget.data.product_uom_qty &lt; 5">
                    <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart text-warning"/>
                </div>
                <div t-elif="widget.data.product_uom_qty == 0">
                    <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart text-danger"/>
                </div>
                <div t-elif="widget.data.product_uom_qty &gt; 5">
                    <a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart text-primary"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work - it makes color of widget in any state yellow (text-warning). I've tried all combinations, great tip on escaping characters! I can't wrap my head around this - if I exclude (comment out) this part


<div t-if="widget.data.product_uom_qty != 0 and widget.data.product_uom_qty &lt; 5">
<a tabindex="0" t-attf-class="fa fa-area-chart text-warning"/>
</div>


widget is not showing up. If I place it in t-elif or move them around it still only shows them yellow. Like it only accepts this text-warning part

Comment: I tested the above code on Odoo15 and it works

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, db i needed this on is v14. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it could help you